# SQL: SUM OR COUNT with CASE WHEN condition in multiple criteria

Tags: sql, syntax, count, sum, criteria

| Course name | Section number | Course type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MATH 101 | 1 | In person |
| MATH 101 | 2 | In person |
| MATH 101 | 3 | Online |
| MATH 101 | 4 | In person |
| SOC 101 | 1 | In person |
| SOC 101 | 2 | In person |
| SOC 101 | 3 | In person |
| ENGL 201 | 1 | In person |
| ENGL 201 | 2 | Online |
| ENGL 201 | 3 | Online |
| ENGL 201 | 4 | In person |
| PHY 101 | 1 | Online |
| PHY 101 | 2 | Online |

From this table, I'd like to count Courses with only an 'In person' course, an 'Online' course, and both course types.

The query I tried is below.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN coursetype = 'Inperson' AND coursetype = 'Online' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bothtype, 
SUM(CASE WHEN coursetype = 'Online'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Onlineonly, 
SUM(CASE WHEN coursetype = 'Inperson'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Onlineonly 
From Course
```

The result what I expected is

| bothtpye | Onlineonly | Inpersononly |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

but I got

| bothtpye | Onlineonly | Inpersononly |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | 6 |

Please advise me to get through this.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to calculate such values ***per course*** and then do another aggregation

Comment: Your query you submitted is not correct you list the same aliases for online and inperson and course type doesn't match your table results.  

What you posted below.  

SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN coursetype = 'Inperson' AND coursetype = 'Online' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bothtype, 
SUM(CASE WHEN coursetype = 'Online'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Onlineonly, 
SUM(CASE WHEN coursetype = 'Inperson'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Onlineonly 
From Course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution uses double conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN In_Person > 0 AND Online > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bothtype,
       SUM (CASE WHEN In_Person > 0 AND Online = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as inpersononly,
       SUM (CASE WHEN In_Person = 0 AND Online > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as onlineonly
FROM (
  SELECT Course_name,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Course_type='In Person' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as In_Person,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Course_type='Online' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Online
  FROM Course
  GROUP BY Course_name
) tot
```

[**DEMO Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kVxCkLMB1FZugt5FrrmBp/0)

Answer (score -1):

SUGGESTION ( using PL/SQL ! ) :

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE countCourses(OUT bothtype INT,OUT Inpersononly INT,OUT Onlineonly INT)
begin
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO bothtype FROM Course;
select COUNT(*) INTO Inpersononly FROM Course
WHERE courseType = "In person";
select  COUNT(*) INTO Onlineonly FROM Course
WHERE courseType = "Online";
end;

call countCourses(@bothtype,@Inpersononly,@Onlineonly);
SELECT @bothtype,@Inpersononly,@Onlineonly;
```

EXPLICATION :

- Creating procedure to store the count of each type of course in OUT  variable
- Call the procedure with convenient parameters
- Select out given parameters